# Forcing https only on one page of a yii website

Tags: .htaccess, yii

I am trying to force https only on one page of a yii framework website, and let the rest of the pages be http. The page that would be forced https is

```
https://www.mywebsite.com/index.php?r=user/profile
```

When I do the following, it forces https on all the pages on the website.

```
RewriteEngine On
# Go to https 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index.php?r=user/profile$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mywebsite.com/$1 [R,L]

# Go to http 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !80 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php?r=user/profile$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mywebsite.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: Out of curiosity: why on earth do you want to prevent pages from using SSL/TLS?

Comment: I am running a shiny app which listens on port 3838. I can't figure out how to make it listen when the SSL security is on. I haven't been able to find a fix, as I am not well versed in port forwarding etc.

Answer (score 2):

The query string isn't part of the `%{REQUEST_URI}` variable, try:

```
RewriteEngine On
# Go to https 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^r=user/profile$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(index\.php)$ https://www.mywebsite.com/$1 [R,L]

# Go to http 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !/index\.php\?r=user/profile
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^r=user/profile$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mywebsite.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: Hi  Jon. That actually worked perfectly. Thank you. The only problem I am now having is that css won't load for that one page. Even when I change the url for the css file to be https, I believe that it is considering the fact the rest of the page was loaded in http and requesting the css file in the sammer. Is there any easy fix to this?

Comment: @MichaelDowers try adding an additional condition to the http redirect (see edit above)

Comment: Thanks Jon. Everything now loads properly. However I get mixed content for the gif and png files that are being gathered through http. (insecure image) Is there anything I could place in htaccess to also gather these images through https? They are being used in the navigation bar.